# Java - How to check is a LocalTime object is before midnight

Tags: java

I am trying to determine if a particular LocalTime is before Midnight. Background basically I want to know if a shift's start/end time bleed over into the next day. For example if a shift was scheduled for 23:00 - 07:00, then this would be considered bleeding into the next day since the end time is after midnight and the start time is before.

I began to implement this by seeing if the start time is before midnight, and seeing if the end time is after midnight. This would meet the criteria of being overlapping into the next day.

In Java my code looks like this

```
public boolean checkTime() {
        
        final LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse("23:00");
        final LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse("07:00");

        return startTime.isBefore(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT) //false
                && endTime.isAfter(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)) //true;
}
```

Why does it return false for the start time being not before midnight? Isn't the time of 23:00 one hour before midnight? I would expect this to return true. Maybe I am misunderstanding something? I am working with LocalTimes and not using LocalDateTimes

Comment: You are checking if 2300 is before midnight of the *same* day, hence why its returning false. See this link for more info http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.time/LocalTime/1040__LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.htm

I would suggest checking if the startTime and Endtime have the same date, and if not, it is bleeding over

Comment: I appreciate the answers everyone. I have a better understanding of the same day limitations that LocalTime has. I marked an answer of accepted that accomplished my needs without having to use a LocalDateTime object.

Comment: _All_ LocalTimes are technically after midnight

Comment: @LouisWasserman Correct (except 00:00 *is* midnight). Or if talking midnight at the end of the day they are all before midnight since they only go up to 23:59:59.999999999.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter(java.time.LocalTime)), for both `isBefore` and `isAfter`:

> The comparison is based on the time-line position of the time within a day.

These methods assume that the times you are comparing are on the same day, so you cannot use these to check if the period "bleeds into" the second day.

Assuming a shift must be less than 24 hours, you can check if it "bleeds into" the second day by checking if the end is before the start. This takes advantage of this "assuming the two times are in the same day" characteristic of `isBefore`. If `isBefore` thinks that `endTime` is before `startTime`, that must mean `endTime` is in the next day.

```
endTime.isBefore(startTime)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Im marking this as accepted since it didn't require me to use LocalDateTime. The POJO I am working on is used heavily throughout our library and it is already using LocalTimes for my situation :)

Answer (score 3):

As with all things, when in doubt, check the documentation.

Here is the documentation for the various parts of your code.

- [`LocalTime#parse(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence))
- [`LocalTime#MIDNIGHT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIDNIGHT)
- [`LocalTime#isBefore(LocalTime)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore(java.time.LocalTime))

The important one is the `LocalTime::isBefore` method. Look at what it says.

*Checks if this time is before the specified time. The comparison is based on the time-line position of the time **within a day**.*

That bolded part isn't completely clear, but what that means is that, it is going to ask if `23` is before `0` ***on the same day***.

More specifically, if May 18 23:00 is before May 18 00:00. As you can see, the answer is false because you accidentally asked for the same day.

You need to use a different tool, likely [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), to be able to solve this problem. Let me know if you have trouble using that tool instead and I can post an example.

Comment: That's assuming that the data you are receiving is good data. For example, if someone accidentally puts 16:00 as their startTime and 08:00 as their endTime, they will get 16 hours of pay instead of 8 hours. The only way to prevent this is to recreate the date functionality (either here, or do it further upstream), hence my point about "use a different tool".

Comment: Correct, but at that point, validation is trivial to do. Doing the same when you only have `LocalTime` is not possible unless you are using another tool instead, or using another tool alongside `LocalTime`.

Answer (score 3):

`LocalTime` only knows the time. It doesn't know anything about the date. [LocalTime.MIDNIGHT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIDNIGHT) is `The time of midnight at the start of the day, '00:00'.`. That's the reason why your code is working like that.

```
startTime.isBefore(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT) == false
```

because `23:00` is after `00:00`.

In the case of

```
endTime.isAfter(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)) == true
```

because `7:00` is after `00:00`

You should consider to use [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

Comment: Actually, that would be `ZonedDateTime` rather than `LocalDateTime`. The first accounts for time zone rules with temporal anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) , while the second lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.